# Why doesn't my first blog entry show up on my last page?

Tags: paging, nodes

On a site that I created a few years ago, my very first blog post does not show up when I browse from the front page to the last page. All my other blog entries seem to show up there. When I manually enter the URL of the first blog post, it loads fine. And when I edit that first blog post it shows as "published".

Why isn't it showing up in the paginated list from the front page?

**Note**: I'm using the default front page display, with Blog module content set to "Promoted to front page". I checked the publication date and it looks fine. I'm not sure what else I can specify. It's basically Drupal showing blog posts on the front page but the very first one for some reason doesn't show up.

Comment: You have to specfiy your situation better. Are you using views to list your blog posts? If so, check your filter settings. Also check the publication date of your blog post if it is not messed (future date perhaps).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I'm using the default front page display, with Blog module content set to "Promoted to front page". I checked the publication date and it looks fine. I'm not sure what else I can specify. It's basically Drupal showing blog posts on the front page but the very first one for some reason doesn't show up.

Comment: I cannot think of a reason this is happening. You are sure your first post was of content type Blog post? One way to solve this is too create a new blog post, set the publication date to the same date as the post that is not showing up and copy the title, body text and give it the same URL-path. Then delete your blog post that is not showing up and your problem should be solved.

Comment: Yes, I just confirmed that it is a blog. I just figured out that for some reason the entry was deselected from "Promoted to Front Page", even though this is the default behavior for blog entries and it was on the front page before. I will post this as an answer. Thank you for your help in troubleshooting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that for some reason this particular blog entry had lost its selection of "Promoted to Front Page" in "Publishing". The content type is set to go to front page by default, and this entry used to be on the front page, so it probably got deselected by accident at some point. Restoring the checkmark fixed the problem.